# Python / IronPython Solution for Excel without Python installed

Tags: ironpython

Is there a way to package an IronPython dll / xll so it can operate on a machine without explicitly installing the interpreter? By that I mean can I somehow package the interpreter inside the dll / xll?

If so what excel solution would you reccomend? I've used ExcelDNA quite a bit for C#, PyXLL also looks good but seems to rely on having Python installed.

Of course, failing this I'll probably end up using VBA - but have made concerted efforts to get away from this. C# addin is still an option, it's just much more time consuming for basic IO, seems to be best left for heavy lifting.

Thanks
Richard

Comment: Here's a thread discussing how to use IronPython and Excel-DNA together: https://groups.google.com/group/exceldna/browse_thread/thread/2202f58934689d77.

Comment: Don't you just need the IronPython.dll, Microsoft.Dynamic.dll and a few Microsoft.Scripting.*.dlls in that same directory? You can possibly pack all of these into a single .xll with ExcelDnaPack.exe.

Comment: Another option would be to explore F#, which integrates a bit better with Excel via Excel-DNA, and would be high-level and succinct enough for you to make nice code.

Comment: Yea will have to. Looks like pyXLL is not going to meet the requirements. C# will do a fine job in the long run, but python seems the perfect language to deal with the pain of interop/IO. ExcelDNA either way is a fantastic utility.

Comment: Have used C# excelDNA to great use, but this involved very little IO and simply stuck an excel front end on high performance code. Such a shame VBA feels like its back to the 1990s compared to .NET and python

Comment: Well, I'm trying hard with Excel-DNA to make .NET a viable alternative to VBA for Excel development. What interop stuff is hard with C#?

Comment: Hi Govert, I know. It's not that anything is hard, it's that its time consuming and gets in the way of RAD. I'm talking about reading and writing to the spreadsheet, having to convert C# datatypes to objects every time. Stuff like this is made much easier when I've used languages like python. When high performant code is not needed IronPython seems like it would work well potentially.

Comment: With the .NET 4 improvements to COM interop, talking to the Excel object model is pretty much as easy in C# as it is from VBA. Also F# should be fine for this (via Excel-DNA). I suggest you post to the Excel-DNA Google group (http://groups.google.com/group/exceldna) if you have any particular questions.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to use [ilmerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx), but I don't know if anyone has tried it with IronPython.

Comment: Probably won't work, since the 'compiled' IronPython assembly isn't a regular managed library. It still needs a lot of help from the runtime to execute.

Comment: You'd have to ilmerge the IronPython runtime in as well.